# Squealing string when muting after strumming

Tags: electric-guitar

I have a Jackson guitar with a floyd rose.

Recently I have changed the tuning from C# standard to E standard which involved a lot of screwing of the springs which hold the floyd rose mechanism.

So after that and changing strings, a weird squealing noise started to appear when I strum the 5th string and then immediately mute it with my palm. An example of that is in the following SoundCloud link:

[SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/dima-birukk/squealing-string?si=ae3dc5cf9c8942e8aa8382267d14943d&utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing)

This also happens when the guitar is not connected to an amp and the other strings seem to be OK.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the assumption it only happens on the *open* A string - and possibly other A notes, it sounds like one of the springs just happens to be at a tension which makes it vibrate sympathetically with that pitch.

Solution: change the tension of the springs very slightly so that none will produce that afternoise.

Comment: Another simple thing to try to remove this possible "wolf tone" is to wrap a rubber band around the springs

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - yes, I did consider a piece of sponge around the springs, if the tension is *exactly* what's needed, but I'm certain that a particular tension isn't that critical. And, by damping the springs, wolf tones are eliminated on all pitches.

Comment: @Tim I'll try that as soon as i get home and report the results, thanks!

Comment: @Tim I've tried to change the spring tension (both tightening and loosening) and still i get this sound. I should note that other A notes are fine - It only happens with the A string.
I've tried to hold the spring in question with my hand while strumming the string and the noise did stop. I'll try the dampening method next. Thanks.

Comment: Yo are talking about the springs that are connected to the claws inside the body? Which generally will be 2 or 3 for the whole block.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, there are 3 springs, the top most is making that noise.

Comment: I think there are several options for placing the springs. Might be worth flicking the offending one out and re-locating it.

Comment: @Tim I've relocated the offending spring as suggested and it worked, no more noise on any string or note. Thanks.